# Regular Expression for matching XML tags and replacing node values

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```xml
<conf-start iso-8601-date="2011-05-31">
   <day>31</day><month>May</month><year>2011</year>
</conf-start>
```

this is the given XML expression and I just wanna replace the `<month>May</month>` to `<month>05</month>` I know it can be done by regular expression but the problem is that I am not that much familiar with regular expressions.

Please, anyone help me with an expression.

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh the is matching XML not HTML, unlike HTML XML must be valid

Comment: @johnny5 it's not just about validation, it's also about regex being poorly suited for recursive matching (like nested levels of matching open/close tags). If you xml is well-formed you are better off using XML - manipulation classes that are available in most languages, not regex.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh yeah, I agree with that, but sometime you don't want the to have to reconstruct the nodes if your doing something simple

Comment: @johnny5 if you have to come to SO to ask, then you are not doing something simple enough for you ;) In this case better stick with the route that is known to work.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh, at one point we all didn't know how to tie our shoes, just because you don't know how to do something doesn't mean its not simple

Answer (score 0):

i try this Pattern **`<month>([^>]*)<\/month>`**

MsgBox(Regex.Replace(y, Regex.Match(y, "([^>]*)</month>").Groups(1).ToString, "05"))

I have worked by hardcoding Month Number.

And put your xml in the place of y.

Sample

```
  Dim y = "<conf-start iso-8601-date=""2011-05-31""><day>31</day><month>May</month><year>2011</year></conf-start>"

        MsgBox(Regex.Replace(y, Regex.Match(y, "<month>([^>]*)<\/month>").Groups(1).ToString, "05"))
```

***Hope this Help***

Comment: this code is displaying only 05 in message box can u please give me more information and i want the data between <conf-start  till </conf-start> and then from there replace <month>

Comment: still not working displaying 05 a number of times i should also be able to see what i am replacing in xml file

Comment: But i'm getting Op like <conf-start iso-8601-date="2011-05-31">
   <day>31</day><month>05</month><year>2011</year>
</conf-start>

Comment: may i know your expected OP

Comment: I have updated my workout in solution.Please check it

Comment: firstly i have to find the line from file which consist line             <conf-start(.*)</conf-start> then from this line i have to find the month tag and change it accordingly.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454